# Ionic: show image from file path from device

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

In an Ionic app the user can select an image from his device (using [this plugin](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker)). Then, with the path from the image (`file://whatever`), I need to show the image in the webview.

```
plugins.imagePicker.getPictures(
    results => {
        this.avatar_path = results[0]
    }
)
```

I cannot use its path (`results[0]`) in the src of the image:

```
<img src="{{ avatar_path }}" />
```

Won't work. Do I need to get the binary from the file (using File API) and set as `<img>` src?

Comment: High likely, most devices won't allow you to directly show the files due to file access. I have no examples for you, but you probably need to cache it locally in app.

Comment: @MathijsSegers this really happens (the console is outputing "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/..." when I try to read it). Do u know how could I cache it locally, only with the file path?

Comment: I'll try with the File Plugin from cordova (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) and check if with this plugin the app can access the device's files.

Comment: Yes follow up on what Chris says, I only have experience working with native apps when it comes to files.

Comment: The author from a plugin helped me: the problem was I that the app was running with a livereload server and then, because of the http sandbox, the requests won't work: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm using this plugin to get access to images stored on the device:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Then in the controller use something like this:

```
$scope.chooseFile = function() {
  var cameraOptions = { quality: 100,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
    targetWidth: 600,
    targetHeight: 600,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG};

  navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI) {

    var nameArr = imageURI.split("/");

    $scope.attachment.name = nameArr[nameArr.length-1];
    $scope.attachment.imageURI = imageURI;

    DbLocalValueService.insertLocalValue("HomeImagePath",$scope.attachment.imageURI);

  }, function(err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  }, cameraOptions);

};
```

And on HTML side use something like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{attachment.imageURI}}" />
```

Also make sure to use ng-src istead of src if you want to change the src of the image on run-time.

With the function DbLocalValueService.insertLocalValue I store the path of the image in a sqlite database and get the value of it on initialization of the view via resolve. You can decide on your own how do you want to store the path of the image.

Comment: I tried to use the plugin but got the same error: "I/chromium(12066): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: content://etc..." it seems Android does not allow to access files from content://

Comment: now it started to work: I was running the ionic app with livereload server and because of this, the app won't load external resources because of cross domain origin. Without livereload, everything started to work. Thanks!

Comment: If everything is clear please accept the answer so the thread gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<img src={{ avatar_path }} />
```

It's work for me but I'm using ionic 1 and same plugin ImagePicker.